# Changing the value of a const pointer

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I have the following piece of code:

```
void TestFunc(const void * const Var1, const float Var2)
{
  *(float*)Var1 = Var2;
}
```

It looks like I am changing the value of the const object the const pointer points to (thanks sharptooth), which should not be allowed. Fact is, none of the compilers I tried issued a warning. How is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As others mentioned, the cast removes the 'constness' of the destination as far as the expression is concerned. When you use a cast the compiler treats the expression according to the cast - as long as the cast itself it valid (and C-style casts are pretty much the big hammer). This is why you don't get an error or warning. You're essentially telling the compiler, "be quiet, I know what I'm doing, this is how you should treat things".  In fact, casts are probably the #1 way for programmers to get the compiler to stop issuing warnings.

Your assignment expression may or may not be undefined behavior. It is permitted to cast away constness **if** the object actually pointed to is not const.

However, if the object pointed to is const, then you have undefined behavior.

```
void TestFunc(const void * const Var1, const float Var2)
{
  *(float*)Var1 = Var2;
}


int
main(void)
{
    float x = 1.0;
    const float y = 2.0;

    TestFunc( &x, -1.0);    // well defined (if not particularly great style)
    TestFunc( &y, -2.0);    // undefined behavior

    return 0;
}
```

You're treading dangerous waters...

In general (I'm sure there are exceptions), casting so that expressions treat objects as they really are is supported, well-defined behavior in C/C++.

This particular behavior is covered in the standards mostly by statements that modifying a const object through a cast (or something) that removes the const qualifier is undefined.  The inference is that doing the same for a non-const object is not undefined.  An example given in the C++ standard makes this clear.

C90 6.5.3 - Type Qualifiers (C99 6.7.3):

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use
>   of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

C++ 7.1.5.1 The cv-qualifiers

> A pointer or reference to a cv-qualified type need not actually point or refer to a cv-qualified object, but it is treated as if it does; a const-qualified access path cannot be used to modify an object even if the object referenced is a non-const object and can be modified through some other access path.  [Note: cv-qualifiers are
>   supported by the type system so that they cannot be subverted without casting (5.2.11).  ]
>
> Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a const
>   object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.
>
> ...
>
> [Example:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> int i = 2;            //not cv-qualified
> const int* cip;       //pointer to const int
> cip = &i;             //OK: cv-qualified access path to unqualified
> *cip = 4;             //ill-formed: attempt to modify through ptr to const
>
> int* ip;
> ip = const_cast<int*>(cip);   //cast needed to convert const int*to int*
> *ip = 4;                      //defined: *ip points to i, a non-const object
>
> const int* ciq = new const int (3);   //initialized as required
> int* iq = const_cast<int*>(ciq);      //cast required
> *iq = 4;                              //undefined: modifies a const object
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Do you happen to have a reference where this is documented for the C language? All I can find is references to const_cast in C++.

Comment: I added the relevant material from the standards.

Comment: I appreaciate it. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

You change the object the pointer points to, not the pointer value.

C-style cast acts like a const_cast and removes the *const* modifier off the pointer. The compiler now has nothing to moan about.

Answer (score 1):

The cast is legal, but the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: That seems like a confusing answer to me.  Using the cast may or may not be undefined behavior, depending on what it's used on.