# Is there a cost to "const"?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, constants

Compilers can sometime exploit the fact that some 'variable' is a constant for optimization, so it's generally a good idea to use the "const" keyword when you can, but is there a tradeoff?

In short, is there a situation where using "const" might actually make the code slower (even  a tiny bit)?

Comment: `const` in C does not mean constant. That doesn't negate the spirit of your question though.

Comment: it can if it forces you using a different algorithm since the data cannot be altered.

Comment: Did you get in an argument with someone over this? The way it's worded makes me wonder if there's some bet taking place. If you give me 30% of the cut, I'll say whatever you want to hear and delete this comment.

Comment: @Chris. Not at all :P I'm reading the code of scientific libraries and I'm seeing a lot of constants without the "const" keyword. I was wondering if there was a reason for this. @bestsss I can see your point, but let's assume the algorithm is unaltered by the "const" keyword.

Comment: @detly: `const` does sometimes mean constant. For example, the compiler is allowed to assume that the value of a `const int` never changes. Not so a `const volatile int`, or the referand of a `const int*`, so it doesn't mean constant in general.

Comment: @Steve - sure, I'm not disputing that, just pointing out that it's not a universal fact that `const` == constant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of optimization does const offer in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466642/what-kind-of-optimization-does-const-offer-in-c-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `const` keyword is used only during compile-time. After the code is compiled the variable is just an address in the memory, without any special protection.

There is some difference, however - **global** `const` variables will be placed in the `text` segment, not the `data` (if initialized) or [bss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) (if uninitialized). If the `text` segment is treated differently, for example executed in place from a NOR flash memory (instead of RAM), there might be a difference. **Local** `const` variables are placed on the stack together with the regular variables, so there should be no difference.

Other than that, as bestsss said, some compile time optimizations might be impossible if the variable is a constant. I can't really think of anything (especially not in pure C), but it is theoretically possible.

Edit:

The following code demonstrated the point in the second paragraph:

```
const int g = 1;
int not_const = 1;

void foo(int param)
{
    int i = 1;
    const int j = 1;

    printf("Variable: \t\t0x%08x\n", (int)&i);
    printf("Const varialbe: \t0x%08x\n", (int)&j);
    printf("Parameter: \t\t0x%08x\n", (int)&param);
    printf("Global const: \t\t0x%08x\n", (int)&g);
    printf("Global non-const: \t0x%08x\n", (int)&not_const);
```

}

In Visual Studio 2010, the result is as follows (note the big difference between the const and non-const global):

> Variable:               0x002af444
>   Const varialbe:         0x002af440
>   Parameter:              0x002af43c
>   Global const:           0x00a02104
>   Global non-const:       0x00a03018

Comment: Your second para is really only about `const` global (or static global) variables — there's also function parameters to consider, which the OP might have also been thinking about.

Comment: @detly - actually, I'm not sure you are correct. There is no difference, compiler-wise, between a global `const` or a function `const` in terms of memory allocation. The only difference is scope.

Comment: Don't function parameters use stack storage?

Comment: @detly - yes, but I thought a `const` is not treated as a regular variable. A test in Visual Studio 2010 confirmed that I was wrong. 
Someone can check with GCC on this one?

Comment: @Eli Iser: `const` variables with automatic storage duration generally get stored on the stack, because if the function were called recursively then each instance of the `const` variable must still have a unique address.  This is why you should almost always make function-scoped `const` variables explicitly `static const`.  (Of course, a clever compiler could perform that optimisation if it sees either that the function cannot be called recursively, or that the address of the `const` object is never taken).

Comment: @caf: for that matter, if the compiler sees that the address is never taken then it can (and GCC does) elide the variable entirely, and just supply the value as an immediate in whatever instructions need it.

Answer (score 4):

A combination of "const" and "non-const" objects can hurt you badly in a rather unexpected way. Some pseudocode:

```
//in some file far far away...
SomeType firstVariable;
const SomeType secondVariable;
```

here these variables look like they are located at adjacent addresses.

On many architectures they will be located far from each other since "const" variables will be placed in a special segment that has write protection during runtime. So interleaved access to those variables will result in more chache misses than you expect and this can considerably slow your program down.

Comment: oh wow, never thought about that. Thanks a lot for your answer !

Comment: @sharptooth, in C you can always cast to void* and do what you wish. I can understand having different layout memory but raising allow the page for read access only seems awkward to me.

Comment: @bestsss: Won't writing to a variable declared const be undefined behavior?

Comment: @sharptooth - no, since `const` is only a compile time directive, which is not enforced during run-time. This is unless the binary loader places the `text` segment in a read-only page (in which case writing to a `const` variable that resides in the `text` segment will cause a segmentation fault).

Comment: @Eli: That sounds like UB to me!

Comment: @Oli, @Eli, @sharptooth, @bestsss — Writing to a `const` object via a recast pointer [certainly is undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771100/changing-the-value-of-a-const-pointer/771114#771114), unless the object was not actually created as a `const` object.

Comment: @detly is correct, and note that this undefined behaviour, as well as allowing the compiler to place the `const` object into a read-only page, also allows the compiler to optimise under the assumption that the `const` object is never modified.  For example, given `const int N = 8;`, the compiler can completely unroll the loop `for (i = 0; i < N; i++)` into a fixed number of iterations, which *won't change even if you use pointer casting to modify N*.

Comment: @caf, just a small nitpick, it's not the compiler that places memory into pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can imagine an architecture where there's memory that is non-writable during program execution **and** accessing that memory is slower that accessing "usual" memory (because of extra checks during each access for example). This is highly unlikely - in most cases "const" will work at least as fast as "non-const".

Comment: Actually this is quite common in embedded applications - the code might be ran from a NOR flash (or some other random access non-volatile memory), which might be slower to access.

Answer (score 1):

It is always possible for an optimizer to fail in various interesting ways, in this case and others. For example, I had a problem recently when the GCC optimizer replaced a memcmp call with a machine instruction. This was supposed to be faster, but on a 64-bit architecture it seems that this instruction was emulated, and it turned out to be slower than the explicitly coded loop inside memcmp.