# Performance advantages of const qualifier in C11

Tags: c, performance, constants, c11

The advantages of the 'const' qualifier have been discussed in various questions, but these discussions relate mostly to failsafes against unintentional modification and clarity of intent. I would like to ask if there is any difference in the resulting program due to the use of the qualifier- in particular, is there a performance gain?

In one of the other questions it was noted that the compiler could not use the natural assumption of an object not changing if passed to a function with the const qualifier given the existence in C++ of 'const_cast'. That is not in C11, so does const allow any optimizations in C11 that would be missed without it?

Another possibility for performance differences is in the memory layout in the case of static objects. Is there any performance advantage to having an object in read only space? This may be hardware dependent, I'd be interested in both general insights and comments specific to particular configurations.

EDIT: It would be a very broad request to ask for a general argument asserting that there cannot be a performance gain making necessary use of 'const'. However, a negation of this assertion would probably be a fairly concise response. So, to be more particular, and without excluding anything addressing my general question, answer forms that would be particularly helpful are as follows:

1. Any example of a case where a performance gain is achieved using 'const' in a necessary way.
2. Any argument as to why the compiler can't make an optimization because of the use of 'const'. This would probably not be hardware specific, and so if this is the case, it probably can be given concisely. If this needs to be more specific, I am most interested in the use of 'const' in function calls.
3. Any answer as to whether read only memory can be used with static objects to achieve a performance gain in desktop or server implementations of x86-64.

This being said, I would appreciate the most general answer to the question as initially stated as is reasonable to provide.

Comment: Are you talking about the const qualifier on objects, or on the target type of a pointer?  The performance implications are quite different.

Comment: I would be interested in either case. I want to get an idea of when, if ever, there is a performance advantage to using 'const'.

Comment: The space of answers is vast. Depends greatly on usage. Can you provide some insight into your application domain or is this question strictly academic? I can try to generate some tests and read assembly output from compilers but who is to say that my tests are even remotely relevant to you?

Comment: I am most interested in x86-64 as implemented in both modern desktop and server CPUs. However, I am also interested in this question from an academic standpoint, and I would be interested in any example at all showing a performance advantage for 'const' use. I have heard both proposed explanations given above for a performance gain, but I have never been able to verify these assertions in any way.

Comment: Jack, I think you are going to have to do something to narrow your question. Particularly what are you qualifying as `const` and are you limiting your discussion to **C11** specifically, or to the use and implication of `const` generally across **C98 -> C11**. While the academic question is interesting, it by itself, does not lend itself to an answer in the reasonable space of a SO question.

Comment: I am only interested in strict C11. I understand that there is a really vast range of situations included in my question, but I am hoping just one concrete example of a performance gain making necesary use of the 'const' qualifier in any way can be presented. It would probably be out of scope to demonstrate that this cannot happen, and for that reason, I am interested in any restricted sets of situations where this is the case. A negative answer that would be particularly helpful would be if it cannot help with performance to use 'const' in a function definition with x86-64.

Comment: @jack: I have gotten a 2x-3x speedup by fixing my const correctness. Unfortunately I don't recall the details, but i think it was that it convinced the compiler that a lookup table used in an inner loop really wasn't changing throughout the lifetime of the program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of optimization does const offer in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466642/what-kind-of-optimization-does-const-offer-in-c-c)

Answer (score 4):

I guess that in principle, a compiler could optimize more when code has a lot of `const` qualifier.

I imagine that with the following code:

```
 extern void foo(const int*const);

 int bar(const int*const arr) {
   int k = arr[0];
   foo(arr);
   return k+arr[0];
 }
```

a clever optimizing compiler could load `arr[0]` only once (and keep the `k` in a local across call to `foo`)

It looks like `gcc-4.9` is not able (or not willing) of such an optimization, but `clang-3.5` is optimizing it (both with `-O3 -fverbose-asm` on Linux/x86-64).

BTW, it is not specific to C11, I believe that with C99 semantics the compiler is allowed to optimize also.

Comment: Does the standard actually *permit* such an optimization? My expectation is no, and that such an optimization can only safely be done at link time.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I believe that it is permitted. If you feel that `clang` is wrong, submit a bug report to it.

Comment: Really, I was hoping you had a standard reference to back up your claim. :( Try making a program where `bar` is called with a dynamically allocated array and `foo` casts away the constness and modifies `arr[0]`. Does `clang` still do the optimization? Also, a version where `bar` is called with the address of an `extern` global array, and `foo` is implemented to modify that array through the global pointer.

Comment: @Hurkyl; I would believe that your cases are undefined behavior. Maybe `arr` should also be qualified `restrict`?

Comment: @Hurkyl, can you cast away constness without undefined behaviour? I thought you had to maintain qualifiers to keep the behaviour defined. The globally available pointer thing makes a good point though.

Comment: Such optimizations are allowed, you can find that in 5.1.2.3 "Program execution" para 10: ...  *In such an implementation, at the time of each function entry and function
return where the calling function and the called function are in different translation units, the values of all
externally linked objects and of all objects accessible via pointers therein would agree with the abstract
semantics. ...*

Comment: @Jens Gustedt, on my reading that paragraph is saying that external function entry defines a point where all externally linked objects, and objects accessible thereby, are in agreement with the values they should have with no optimization. This does not justify making an optimization that changes behaviour. In fact, the point of the paragraph is to not make optimizations that change behaviour by ignoring changes in externally linked objects.

Comment: @jack: I'm unfortunately unfamiliar with the details of when const casts are safe, but I am currently under the impression that modifying objects so pointed to is well-defined behavior whenever the objects being pointed to themselves weren't created as constants.

Comment: I don't think the compiler should assume that the contents of `arr` are not changed by `foo`, unless the definition of `foo` is in the same translation unit.  `foo` may well have a side effect on a global array to which a pointer was passed to `bar()`.  C does not have a `pure` qualifier that would give the compiler this information. IMHO `restrict` does not really fix this issue. I agree with @jack: `clang` seems overly optimistic, but the optimisation would be OK if `arr` was defined locally in `bar()`.