# C++ Immutability of classes and pros/cons

Tags: c++

There are three ways I know of to create an immutable object.

Method 1: internally immutable class members, internally and externally unmodifiable.

```
#ifndef INTERNALLY_IMMUTABLE_HPP
#define INTERNALLY_IMMUTABLE_HPP

#include <string>

class internally_immutable
{
public:
    internally_immutable(const std::string & str)
    : str_(str)
    {
    }

    std::string get_str() const
    {
        return str_;
    }

private:
    const std::string str_;
};

#endif
```

Method 2: externally immutable class members, externally unmodifiable.

```
#ifndef EXTERNALLY_IMMUTABLE_HPP
#define EXTERNALLY_IMMUTABLE_HPP

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class externally_immutable
{
public:
    externally_immutable(const std::string & str)
    : str_(str)
    {
    }

    std::string get_str() const
    {
        return str_;
    }

private:
    std::string str_;
};

#endif
```

Method 3: type immutable, partially externally unmodifiable, as someone could bypass your typedef.

```
#ifndef TYPED_IMMUTABLE_HPP
#define TYPED_IMMUTABLE_HPP

#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef const typed_mutable typed_immutable;

class typed_mutable
{
public:
    typed_mutable(const std::string & str)
    : str_(str),
    vec_()
    {
    }

    void set_str(const std::string & str)
    {
        str_ = str;
    }

    std::string get_str() const
    {
        return str_;
    }

private:
    std::string str_;
};

#endif
```

What are the pros and cons of each immutable type? Compiler optimizations, impediments, usage of each type... Are there other ways of creating immutable objects in C++? What is the recommended, or most common way to create these immutable classes in C++?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to return `const` values from member functions. In any case, it doesn't impact the mutability of the object the member function is being called on.

Comment: @juanchopanza it may not make sense from a user endpoint but what about a compilation endpoint?

Comment: I don't know what it means to make sense "from a compilation standpoint".

Comment: @juanchopanza Any optimizations the compiler could make knowing the returned value won't be modified.

Comment: That is posing some restrictions (that can be easily bypassed) just in the hope of some optimizations. I would consider it only if it really is necessary. But it is a different topic to your question.

Comment: @juanchopanza The third is partially immutable, because if a user bypasses your typedef they can use the class in an unexpected manner.
This topic is relevant to my question i believe.

Comment: Now it is different because you just edited it to make it so.

Comment: @juanchopanza woah. relax. I noticed I mis-copy pasted. This was the intention of my question, read the comment above which I did not edit.

Comment: Sorry about that. Going back to the `const` return values, that can actually work against you because it will disallow move semantics. In your example, you have two types that are efficiently movable. It is one more thing to consider.

Comment: It makes no sense to return a const vector from a function, from any standpoint.

Comment: thank you, good things to know even if irrelevant to the question. I will edit the question to be correct in this sense.

Comment: I found this question on a different stackexchange that is kind of relevant in that they describe the difference between logical immutability vs immutability:
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149555/difference-between-immutable-and-const

Comment: @juanchopanza this stack exchange question validates the importance of what you mentioned as const return types do not perform any kind of optimization
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466642/what-kind-of-optimization-does-const-offer-in-c-c

Answer (score 0):

you can make the immutable class when will you make your constructor private in this case your derived class can't access base class.
like as .
    class externally_immutable
    {
    private :
    externally_immutable(const std::string & str)
    : str_(str){}
    // to do
    const string str_;
};