# Why clang does not optimize global const like a #define?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, clang, constants

I have this test program, using a `#define` constant:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOO 1

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", FOO);

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with “Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)”, I get an executable of 8432 bytes. Here is the assembly listing:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 10, 14
    .globl  _main                   ## -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $1, %esi
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   _printf
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)          ## 4-byte Spill
    movl    %esi, %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ## -- End function
    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:                                 ## @.str
    .asciz  "%d\n"


.subsections_via_symbols
```

Now I replace `#define FOO 1` with `const int FOO = 1;`. The executable is now 8464 bytes and the assembly listing looks like this:

```
.section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 10, 14
    .globl  _main                   ## -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $1, %esi
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   _printf
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)          ## 4-byte Spill
    movl    %esi, %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ## -- End function
    .section    __TEXT,__const
    .globl  _FOO                    ## @FOO
    .p2align    2
_FOO:
    .long   1                       ## 0x1

    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:                                 ## @.str
    .asciz  "%d\n"


.subsections_via_symbols
```

So it actually declared a `FOO` variable, making the executable 32 bytes bigger.
**I get the same result with `-O3` optimization level.**

Why is that? Normally, [the compiler should be intelligent enough to optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27466684) and add the constant to the symbol table instead of taking up storage for it.

Comment: You're using clang, not gcc...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is another case where the difference between C and C++ matters.

In C, `const int FOO` has external linkage and must thus be included in the binary.

Compiling with g++ or clang++ instead gives you the desired optimization as `FOO` has internal linkage in C++.

You can achieve the optimization in C mode by explicitly requesting internal linkage for `FOO` via

```
static const int FOO = 1;
```

Both clang and gcc with link-time optimization enabled (`-flto`) also manage to strip away the unused symbol, even when linkage is external. (Live [with](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3aed40b9ce846dc) and [without](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee20f2264714bba7) LTO.)

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you use the variable `FOO` in your second program means that it has to live somewhere, so the compiler needs to allocate it somewhere.

In the `#define` case, there is no variable - the pre-processor substituted the text "FOO" with the text "1" an so the call to `printf()` was passed a constant value, not a variable.

Comment: @Deduplicator  - not quite sure what you are getting at.  "foo" defined in OP's test.c needs to be defined, b/c the compiler has no idea if that test.o will be linked against some source.c which will access "foo".  While the compiler was smart enough to replace the variable with a constant in the call to printf (at least that what I think its doing with "movl    $1, %esi") - the linker is not analyzing all your code again to determine that a particular variable is unused.

Comment: *"the linker is not analyzing all your code again to determine that a particular variable is unused."* It is if you tell it to.

Comment: "It is if you tell it to" - I just saw that.  As that was added to 2009 - way after I moved from the C world - I was unaware.  That said, the object file (and the assembly) generated is always going to have that symbol defined b/c that is the input to the linker.