# Does a restrict-qualified pointer parameter of a function allow optimization of the caller functions?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, compiler-optimization, restrict-qualifier

A restrict-qualified pointer parameter of a function is an effective way to allow compilers to optimize **that function**:

```
int f(const int *restrict p) {
  int n=*p;
  printf("Debug\n");
  return *p==n;
}
```

Here Clang 17 with -O3 will just return 1 without re-examining `*p`, and without performing the comparison.
Without `restrict`, `*p` has to be re-examined and the comparison has to be performed. This is because `printf` is an external function, and the compiler doesn't know if it might modify `*p`. Indeed, if `p` happens to be pointing into the file position indicator of `stdout`, `printf` is actually going to modify it.

So, as a general principle, if you want maximum optimization for **the function**, and your function ever calls an external function, it is not meaningless to declare all your parameters `restrict`. Of course, this places a severe restriction on callers, because it requires them to promise that they will not call your function with pointers aliased into unexpected places.

My question goes further than this observation. I ask if `restrict` permits optimization of **the callers of your function** too?

```
int f(const int *restrict p);
int caller(int *p) {
  int n=*p;
  f(p);
  return *p==n;
}
```

It would seem to me that this guarantees to the compiler that `f` will not modify `*p`, thus it can omit re-examining `*p` and the comparison, and can safely return 1. Neither Clang nor GCC do this optimization.

I know it's OK that they don't optimize the caller. I am asking whether the are permitted to optimize. (This is primarily a question about the semantics of my program, not about performance.)

Comment: Note that a very effective way to let your callers be optimized is to declare the function pure: `int f(const int *p) __attribute__((pure));` (would be `[[reproducible]]` in the upcoming C23 standard). However, here `f` is not pure (as it prints to `stdout`). Hopefully `restrict` is a way to say that the function is pure *with respect to that particular pointer*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this code:

```
int f(const int *restrict p);
int caller(int *p) {
  int n=*p;
  f(p);
  return *p==n;
}
```

the compiler cannot conclude that `*p` does not change during execution of `f` because the code below shows a definition of `f` and a call to `caller` in which the behavior is defined (does not violate the `restrict` requirements) yet the value of `*p` changes during execution of `f`:

```
extern int m[2];

int f(const int * restrict p)
{
    m[0] = 3;
    return p[1];
}

void bar(void)
{
    caller(m);
}
```

When `f` is called in this case, `p` points to `m[0]`, so `*p` is `m[0]`. Since `f` changes `m[0]`, the value of `*p` changes during execution of `f`, but this does not violate the `restrict` requirements because the `restrict` definition only imposes requirements if `p` is used, directly or indirectly, to access the object. C 2018 6.7.3.1 4 says:

> During each execution of `B`, let `L` be any lvalue that has `&L` based on `P`. If `L` is used to access the value of the object `X` that it designates, and `X` is also modified (by any means), then the following requirements apply:…

In the above `f`, `m[0]` is accessed only through the lvalue `m[0]` and not through any lvalue whose address is based on `p`. So the prerequisite condition for `restrict` never occurs for `m[0]`, so it imposes no constraints on whether or how `m[0]` is modified.

Comment: That is a very good example, especially the fact that your `f` is meaningfully accessing something through `p`, but not accessing `*p` itself through `p`. Exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: It demonstrates that `restrict` just cannot be used to optimize callers of a function period, no matter what other qualifications/tricks (such as `const`) you attempt to add.

Answer (score 3):

Two reasons this optimization isn't legal for an unknown `f(const int *restrict p)` when the `caller()` can only see a prototype:

- The `restrict` stuff only applies to objects that were actually *accessed* via the `restrict` pointer.  `f` could ignore its arg (or access `p[1]` but not `p[0]`) and modify the caller's object via a global pointer.  CPPreference omits this part of the ISO C standard's definition.
- `f` can legally cast away a `const` qualifier and modify the object unless the underlying object is `const`, so the optimization isn't valid even if there can't be any other pointer to the object floating around.

---

**In general it's legal to cast away `const`, as long as the pointed-to object itself wasn't defined as `const`.**  The optimization you're suggesting would break with this `f` in this program which I think is free of UB:

```
void f(const unsigned *restrict p) {
    unsigned *unqualified_p = (unsigned*)p;
    ++*unqualified_p;  // *restrict p still exists but this pointer was derived from p
}
```

```
unsigned global;
int main(){          // aka caller(int *p)
    unsigned n = global;
    f(&global);
    return n == global;
}
```

This compiles cleanly with clang or `gcc -O2 -Wall -Wextra`.  [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYgATKVpMGoAPrnkpJfWQE8Ayo3QBhVLQCuLBhNJOAMngMmAByngBGmMT6AJykAA6oCoT2DK4eXj4JSXYCAUGhLBFRAKxWmDY5DEIETMQEaZ7eXGUVKdW1BHkh4ZExVjV1DRnNCgOdgd2FvcUAlFao7sTI7BwA9KsA1ACSG%2B5K6LsMScBBBwqoG6gAbpFUtKgA7gC0cgBCG3gKHyxZSWH0pAApBoAILrDYbIgbJSYDYPBBMAgbcpKDZvITGOELWgHe6oADWG34xGBYM2AHFnM4NsgEJhkPivsSNsE5H4/BtjAcxHgTmxBJcGJC6RsEoECJFSJCHnhlgA6UngrZIuLEVBhJj/ACeG3QqEwCgYYA4SNp9MJzOIBoIxFlSKu9iMlS%2Bxi1DyYWql52Fn11%2BsNxpVapuGxY7lppKuqDwByoEDQRyR7iOvNOGwAVFbRrbbKKZhtAQB2V6kiEQ5PHNPp5MAR3cPJomHQpjiBYAzAARDYQCuppvpmZxQFtkugssFvQlyfVhh1ht4Jst4ejkFFjuk0m9k5NjbAe4a2jLxXpj4C0S0ejEHsp7cHdNxfNFlflm9phjDjv3o9jokQB/fkEIStAhFiFL9Ow/d8Rw3Qt11BTdXx3Pd1TEADxVDJhAggGYn1LMtgNAiFz0vbtAT0AA2ZCDxw6D4Ng0t01WDdQXBBhUAIBBAmAIkSBpIwTDRV4FExKFMBuIUzQZHiSVBdCWEwhhsNwn8X0rHchQ/Xd91Q2jALLOMyMo7TaBo598MwEDiCFDSIM7LSUMPXS11JDg5loThil4bwOC0UhUE4alzkWZYJzbPReAITRXLmOkmCwKJsNIfEQDbLg5Q0SRCwyvQuCkQtimiQsKMMThJF4FgJA0DRSG83z/I4XgFBAarIp81zSDgWAYCgbqICQNAfjoSUKHjVBBsvFBgC4MK%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%2B1IaXyRKgKgZdK7V1rsAeujc2zN27K4cakRQptm7gfXu/dB4JQQZPCqehJDpUkNENsqVN5tiqlwZeyC6q7ysPvQ%2B0UkogFHiVDgbZi4oKEaI4%2BvVer9TGnfS819RrkKiPXfiU0srNBoLQeai1lp3TWswPa5MdoWIOkdE6VjzqMEutdW6vkHpPRehed620voc1%2Bm4vAAM7DAxWmDCGUMPrkEELDO68NEbIwwCsXy6NMY8GxkYPGhNMDE1Jt5baoDqbiDpqAxmECWY%2BF0SAcwphLBxONvzQWKR3qi3FpLaWos5ZI0VsrNWGtOxa0wDrJsesbjEENgaeAcxg6VAtlbdITRfCW0zk7ZoPsUip1WYkN2DBlkB2jiHKoYwNn7MqGHcY%2BQE4%2BFGCnCOCzrkZwdpcrgUyFhLHzggpBtU9acBwa/WuyBdGN0LOlOUXBuxt1/qFAuPc2p91ILFeKlA5gjzHqVcqIBCzl1BRoDekgpBcHLnoDh0RpBfL8kIpqLVe4dWUWfdBV8Rq33vo/NgnAX54L4hzIFILtpNnbn/AwBSgESBAbIUpzNfK6GaDApgcCsZSM%2BTvDgaCL6Q0uNg9lb8AVcq4MCjQoLSGqPvqFZ5MKj50MRYlceTD9BpQ3nw4o5dHW6o0ORDQhYBHfIasIqlsLkUSNRdI2RgjvUKP9YvWexQiXFExU6lhGg9AevHl/CqfDqpkvqmasRyb0Vps9eS0NtDSCjKSA4SQQA%3D%3D). (And runs cleanly with  `-fsanitize=undefined`, although I wouldn't be confident of UBsan catching const or restrict cast violations if I'm wrong and this isn't well-defined.)

---

Example of just the `const` part being enough to defeat optimization, with escape analysis giving the compiler everything you were hoping it could infer from `restrict`:

```
void g(const int *p);

int bar(){
    int a = 1;      // non-escaped local, no global pointer to it can exist
    g(&a);
    return a == 1;  // actually compares, not returning a constant
}
```

Optimization wouldn't be valid in this case.  Unfortunately this demo isn't as good as I'd hoped because GCC and clang miss a valid optimization for passing a pointer to a `const int` local variable where the callee *can't* change it, because the actual object itself is `const`.  A `g` that casted away `const` and modified the object would be UB.  (If the initializer is a compile-time constant, compilers do constant propagation even across a call that passes the address.)  ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYgATKVpMGoAPrnkpJfWQE8Ayo3QBhVLQCuLBhNJOAMngMmAByngBGmMT6AMykAA6oCoT2DK4eXj4JSXYCAUGhLBFRerHWmLYpQgRMxARpnt5cVpg2OQxVNQR5IeGRMVbVtfUZTQqDXYE9hX0lAJRWqO7EyOwcAG6oeOgA1MAQaAxj24EE2wBUcbMApNEAQlcaAIIPjyfbYTUQ1wDs90/bAOOgm2TG2NwAItsuDdboDAQB6eHbBgCAC0mAUojimB2tFQolopGRqF2eI%2BtG2CROkW2RGOp1EDG2mFUeDGLzheyuegAbExrncOYDiJgCEsmaCIRCoTCAYiQbZ3GJaABPbZoFhxGoYoko04isXEBiBYAg9UCMbGAgvK7fcE2p5vD4ALwgb1UPz%2BjzhByOb0l0UhqiJYTBge2qllcPlKIY6MxTGxuPxYgURNoeAA1phaQgc1R3AwKgIQcRgEK5UjjDsCHntoWsMRVSbtqgwtpygQFKWc77TgoSYRtgB3Ra0HYRbZyWH8Yi7Wkk5AIYzAHO1zAsCu7CDcvkCr1wg3is1S8NhKPygDizmcIIYO2QRhM2zGdApGq1IrAYC38qPRojMN7TPC8kXQVAMVbOI7BYPBnRzRZTnXc1NW1XVMEIPM5zxAlmQTbEFBtO0HWeR1gQ%2BZYvltA9AT7IFTgDSFoUFf5AS5Xl%2BRhLd/wlIDpWY2FtnlcDIL7K1KWIVAtWAJgCEwIj7SeDh5loTgAFZeG8DgtFIVBOFvAclhWMESj0XgCE0ZT5jzJhG0oeZMxAaIuAAOg0SRvncvQuCkb41IATm%2BXlDE4SReBYCQNA0UgtJ0vSOF4BQQGiiztOU0g4FgGAoGyiAkA/OhInISgCvoKJkGALhogMGhaDk4gkogMJLNIMJAhqFVOB4Vr2uIFUAHl207LreA1NhBH6hhVRarAwncYBnGVJLuF4LAWBXcQ0tIfARQqNYMRallyncOSRvIQQWhajMwmIDrXCwFqCGIPAIpW%2BYqCMYAFAANTwTBh367EtO6/hBBEMR2CkGRBEUFR1C23RYifMwLEMPAwiSyB5iktpltRAB1ZVtlRfq9GJ/GWSe0FeFQfbiGerBMa%2BZpWhSRx72GRpfHvboCiKTJEmSAROYF7IUl53oolGFpO0qcYRel1mBA6WoJemKWBk6BXNdVyY%2Bb6Lh5kM5Z2D0FT1M0lr4ojAAOHlUR5SRdmQZAoWiFyyYgXBCBIEzqtmczLNmazMFsvpmcctTotUjgwtICK/Jc/yo55HkbY0aIeX8/ybf8nkYqtzhEuS0hUq0eZMsQEBELiE7iv2VBNUK4hglYVZVDth2neAF23Y93gcR9hn9Gh4QCUh6RQfkJQ1BaxHSGHW64hG82OA0gutvi/qTtr05UCoW37cd53Xaqj3tggVwm7Kv3ogD0ug5DsOomZmO44ivRJDcyR/OiZy8%2BiFFLgGcN5xSLlYEuZcrKkEjtHTg0RLab3AVAiuuVcr5UbnEZu9dSp9BdsjLgnkmi1Xqo1ZqW02rMD6mdShHVBodlsGdMajACCTWmltWa81Fq0FoMtbqa0NqrB0jtWW%2B1lo6SOsgE6qxurUhjjpa6t0%2Br3SEeZZ6r0eDvU%2Bj9P6AMgZnSnuDcQUMp6w1ngjHwyMQDmFMJYa6TNsbQRSHjQmPDiak3JpTW6NM6YMwOljFmssHAQCcNrfwetJaiyFqkNwDQoltDVvzRWQT2jy1iSMQJxZUmdESQbHWdR0lc0tLrfIkTDYLCMqbVe69Yo004IfLu6pkZQm%2BG5FyXAL7eyIHObk/tA5pWDqQGydkI4gCjiFWO4UQDfBtu0jQudJBSC4DbPQv9/LSFqbpcBSUUpBwyug6uO864UAbtfSIrc2CcA7kfJ2j4VwtLad1Qe3Stgj0MePCQk9ZBmPhjpXQTRF6JhXhMmphcODbwILvVsB9rmNLuc%2BQhjyL5XywTfXpht%2BnlyfiM1e799CuVzsAtSNtiWEI0DyDQ3xQF1IShA3ZAyHJjLgRwBB1Ktm0pQYytOSc1KrLUjMkln8NB6CpTHMy8dIrRU2fFTF0CxVTOAVKsFsrBl0ySA4SQQA%3D)).

```
int baz(int x){
    const int a = x, b = x;     // non-escaped locals, like the function arg
    // and the underlying objects are const so it would be UB for g to change them
    g(&a);
    return a == b;  // GCC and clang still compare!
    // return x == b;  // does optimize out the compare, neither local escapes
}
```

```
int barc(){
    const int a = 1;
    g(&a);
    return a == 1;  // constant folding to return 1
}
```

---

#### `restrict` only kicks in on access.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict says *if some object that is accessible through P (directly or indirectly) is modified, by any means, then all accesses to that object (both reads and writes) in that block must occur through P (directly or indirectly)* [otherwise UB].

But the requirement isn't just that the object is accessible, it's that it actually was accessed.  (Thanks @Eric Postpischil for catching this.)  From the [C 2018 standard (n2310)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf#page=102), *6.7.3.1 Formal definition of restrict*

> [definitions of B as a block, P as a `restrict` pointer, etc.]
>
> 4. During each execution of B, let L be any lvalue that has &L based on P. **If L is used to access the
>    value of the object X that it designates**, and X is also modified (by any means), **then the following
>    requirements apply**:
>    T shall not be const-qualified. Every other lvalue used to access the value of
>    X shall also have its address based on P. Every access that modifies X shall be considered also to
>    modify P, for the purposes of this subclause. If P is assigned the value of a pointer expression E that
>    is based on another restricted pointer object P2, associated with block B2, then either the execution
>    of B2 shall begin before the execution of B, or the execution of B2 shall end prior to the assignment.
>    If these requirements are not met, then the behavior is undefined.
> 5. Here an execution of B means that portion of the execution of the program that would correspond to
>    the lifetime of an object with scalar type and automatic storage duration associated with B.
>
> [later stuff is all just examples, no further clauses that impose any restrictions on behaviour.]

Everything is conditional on the value actually being accessed via a `restrict` pointer.  This is confirmed earlier in 6.7.3 with "*An object **that is accessed through** a restrict-qualified pointer has a special association with that
pointer...*"

```
int *global_ptr;
// No UB even if called with p == global_ptr
void f1(const int *restrict p) {
   *global_ptr = 1;  // which happens to point at the same object as p
}

// also legal with p == global_ptr
void f2(const int *restrict p) {
   p[1]++;
   *global_ptr = 1;  // points at p[0]
}
```

The CPPreference page about C `restrict` appears to also have a mistake in its discussion of `const`, in the *function parameter* section. They talk about the possibility of `f` taking `float const * restrict b` and what that implies, but it's written as if casting away `const` wasn't legal. (Unless I'm misreading what they're saying and they meant with the actual definition visible, not just a prototype.)

Comment: Re “You're right that the caller can assume `*p` wasn't accessed via any other path, though”: No, the caller cannot assume that. The formal definition of `restrict` imposes constraints only if an lvalue based on `p` is used to access an object. If the function never accesses `*p` via `p` (e.g., only uses `p` for comparison or accesses `p[1]` but not `p[0]`), then `*p` may be changed by other means (modified through another pointer or through an external identifier).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That's not what CPPreference says; perhaps they got that wrong?  They say if the pointed-to object is modified at all (which could include via `*global_ptr`), then all access to it within the block must be via `p`.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict - *if some object that is accessible through P (directly or indirectly) is modified, by any means, ...*  Oh, hmm, the case you're talking about doesn't have any accesses to `*p` via `p` in the block itself, only via the other path.  (From a different block, but during the lifetime of `p`.)

Comment: C 2018 6.7.3.1 4 says “During each execution of `B`, let `L` be any lvalue that has `&L` based on `P`. If `L` is used to access the value of the object `X` that it designates, and `X` is also modified (by any means), then the following requirements apply:…” That is the only paragraph in the definition of `restrict` that imposes constraints. cppreference.com is wrong. Consider a copy routine that copied from one pointer and offset to another pointer and offset. Should it violate `restrict` when the caller passes the same pointer with different offsets for non-overlapping segments?

Comment: More simply, `extern int m[2]; int f(int * restrict p) { m[0] = 3; p[1] = 4; } void bar(void) { f(m); }` has defined behavior because, while the object designated by `*p` changes in `f`, it is never accessed by an lvalue `L` whose address `&L` is based on `p`. It is only accessed by `m[0]`, which is not based on `p`.

Comment: @PeterCorders, I agree with both of your points, both are very relevant. Neglecting `const` semantics of C was my mistake. The second point about access is at the heart of `restrict` semantics, which was what the question was primarily about. So I am going to accept Eric's answer, which seems to be the first to make the point about access. Truly sorry that I cannot accept both answers, I do hope readers will read both.

Comment: @log65536: I think C++ is the same here, you can round trip a pointer to a non-const object through a `const T*` and back and deref without UB; stuff like this is what `const_cast<T>` is for.  (Edit: I see you reposted your comment without mention of C++ being different.) And yeah, that part of my answer was purely prompted by Eric's comments, and is certainly the more interesting point about how `restrict` works in general, outside the application to this optimization question.  I'd hope people would upvote both answers, but Eric deserves the credit for spotting the fundamental thing.